# GDB Loading the incorrect library

Tags: gdb, cgdb

I have two different version of a library let's say
    libxyz.so

at two different location

```
1) /home/maverick/dev/libxyz.so ( development Version)
2) /home/maverick/prod/libxyz.so ( Production Version )
```

I have a setup that compile my program and link with appropriate version of the library depending on LD_LIBRARY_PATH. for example If I want to link my program with dev version of libxyz.so i change my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add /home/maverick/dev and if I want to link with prod version I change LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add /home/maverick/prod instead.

I compiled my program by linking with dev version and the output of

```
ldd MyProg
```

is

```
libxyz.so => /home/maverick/dev/libxyz.so
```

If i run the program it loads the libxyz.so from

```
/home/maverick/dev/libxyz.so
```

and runs fine.
it this point my LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes /home/maverick/dev not /home/maverick/prod

but when I try to debug this program through GDB

```
gdb MyProg
```

it loads the libxyz.so from location

```
/home/maverick/prod/libxyz.so
```

I have trouble making GDB load the correct version of the library during debug. So till now what I am doing is first launch the program (that load the dev version) and attach gdb to that PID this way its works fine. but if it run like

```
gdb MyProg
```

it dosen't

I tried every thing to fix this like setting up sysroot, solib-search-path in GDB but nothing is working.
if fact when I set up sysroot to point to the debug version of the library gdb gave some message like

```
.dynamic section for XXX is not at the expected address
```

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have trouble making GDB load the correct version of the library during debug.

Let me guess: you are using `tcsh`, right?

The problem most likely comes from yoour `~/.cshrc` resetting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/home/maverick/prod`.

When you `run` the program in GDB, it executes `$SHELL -c your-program [args...]` (so as to allow you to use I/O redirection).

Solution: don't touch environment in your `.cshrc` for non-interactive shell, e.g. start it with:

```
if ($?prompt  ==  0) exit
```

Comment: when gdb execute 
$SHELL -c your-program [args...]

does my shell (tchs) reads its env from .tcshrc or it use the current env ?

If it reads it from the .tcshrc the problem lies three. coz in .tcshrc LD_LIBRARY_PATH still holds /home/maverick/prod.

Comment: It worked, thanks man.
The root of the problem lies in the fact that GDB runs the program this way

$SHELL -c your-program [args...]

good to know that.